# Who said Hermes helped Hades?

Tags: myth-identification, hades, hermes

[image: Hermes helps Hades abduct Persephone]

Retrieved from [here](http://ancient-greece.org/art/amphipolis-mosaic.html).

This is a mosaic depicting Hades abducting Persephone. Helping him, is Hermes. I do not recall a version of the myth in which Hermes helps Hades. Is there a version, or is this just an artist's interpretation of the myth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any version of the myth that has Hermes helping hades abduct Persephone, although I'm very happy to be corrected on this.

However, I want to suggest an alternative interpretation from the one provided. There is a known part of this myth where all three did travel by chariot: When they were on the way out of Hades domain after Zeus had sent Hermes to tell Hades to let her go.

Example:

> "Making ready his chariot, Hades conveyed Persephone and Hermes back
>   up through the earth until they arrived at Demeter's temple"

https://owlcation.com/humanities/Demeter-and-Persephone

I know this isn't the usual interpretation given to this, I think due to the pose and expression of Persephone, but there are other possible interpretations of this. I found one version of the myth that says:

> The crafty Hades learned this agreement and tricked his reluctant
>   bride, who was crying all day and night from despair, to eat a few
>   seeds of the pomegranate fruit. This was the food of the Underworld
>   and every time someone ate even a few seeds of this, then, after a
>   while, **he would miss life in the Underworld.** When the gathering in front of Zeus took place and Persephone was asked where she would like to live, she answered she wanted to live with her husband.

https://www.greeka.com/greece-myths/persephone.htm

(Emphasis mine)

Which could be the source of the expressive longing on her face.